# Creating Ada record with one field

Tags: ada

I've define a type:

```
type Foo is record
   bar : Positive;
end record;
```

I want to create a function that returns an instance of the record:

```
function get_foo return Foo is
    return (1);
end get_foo;
```

But Ada won't let me, saying "positional aggregate cannot have one argument".
Stupidly trying, I've added another dumb field to the record, and then `return (1, DOESNT_MATTER);` works!

How do I tell Ada that's not a positional aggregate, but an attempt to create a record?

Comment: FYI: In my experience, most "Ada haters" get frustrated because they are trying to code some other language in Ada. Once you learn to actually write Ada, its a very good language. Better than most. However, it makes an incredibly crappy C compiler.

Comment: For example, you *really* have to think out your types. If there are edge cases where you'll try putting a 0 into bar above, you are going to start getting really frustrated with constant `constraint_error`'s.

Comment: As someone who approached Ada optimistically, I was/am frustrated because, unlike other languages, Ada makes it frustratingly difficult to learn the "Ada way of doing it". :) I like the idea of Ada, but I find the implementation to be convoluted and frustrating. I empathize with ada hater. :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The positional aggregate initialization cannot be used with record having only one component, but that does not mean you cannot have record with one component.

The values of a record type are specified by giving a list of named fields. The correct code for your `get_foo` function should be as following.

```
function get_foo return Foo is
    return (bar => 1);
end get_foo;
```

You can also specify the type of the record using the `Foo'(bar => 1)` expression.

Using the list of named components is better in practice than positional initilization. You can forget the position of the component and it does not change if you add a new field into your record.