# Why is named association required for a one-element record aggregate?

Tags: record, ada

When an aggregate contains only one element, as below, positional notation results in a compilation error and we have to use named notation only. Why?

```
type singleton is record
   v : integer;
end record;

v1 : singleton := (0);
```

results in the compiler message

```
check.adb:6:23: positional aggregate cannot have one component
check.adb:6:23: write instead "V => ..."
gnatmake: “check.adb" compilation error
```

whereas this is OK:

```
v2 : singleton := (v => 0);
```

Comment: Because parentheses round an expression are redundant, so (0) = 0 and it's an integer not an array aggregate. Contrast this with (0,0) which can only be an aggregate. This could cause ambiguities in more complex aggregates, multi-dim arrays or arrays in records.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Dude, make that an answer, we'll upvote it!  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parentheses round an expression are redundant, so (0) = 0 and it's an integer not an array aggregate.

So, for the special case of a one-element aggregate, named association is required to distinguish an aggregate from a simple value.

Contrast this with (0,0) which can only be an aggregate; therefore there is no ambiguity.

Even though in the context of the question, it's obvious to a human programmer which is intended, that will not always be the case.

Consider a one-element aggregate in a multi-dimensional array which is one field of a record; there can be ambiguities that the compiler cannot resolve (at least, before reading a whole lot more of the source file!) and would make life pretty difficult for anyone reading the program.

Comment: For completeness, (0,0) could also be a parameter list e.g. to a subprogram call. But it's usually not hard to distinguish those from aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use named notation.

```ada
v1 : singleton := (others => 0);
```

This will assign 0 to all elements in v1 and the compiler will know that is not a number but an array instead.

If the record happen to have different types you could use

```ada
v1 : singleton := (others => <>);
```

Comment: [Creating Ada record with one field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743099/creating-ada-record-with-one-field)