# How do you initialize an array with only one element, without hardcoding the first index?

Tags: arrays, ada

I am trying to pass an array of Unbounded_String to a function, and I don't care about the range of the index, as the function is going to loop over each element.

The (element1, element2) syntax automatically starts at the first index value in the range, then increments for the second value given, which works fine for more than one value. However, for a single value, this cannot be used as the parentheses are considered superfluous.

This code shows the error messages for each of the attempts I have made. (1) works, but (2), the preferable syntax for passing a single-element array, does not. (3) works, and is given as an answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955655/why-is-named-association-required-for-a-one-element-record-aggregate#26976302). However, this hardcodes the first index of the range into the calling side; if the String_Array implementation changes, all the call-sites have to be changed, even though they don't care about the index values used.

```
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;  use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

procedure Main is

  function "+"(S: String) return Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String
    renames Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String;

  type String_Array is array (Positive range <>) of Unbounded_String;

  procedure Foo(input : in String_Array) is
  begin
    null;
  end Foo;

begin
  Foo((+"one", +"two"));                                    --(1)
  --Foo((+"only"));                                         --(2) positional aggregate cannot have one component
  Foo((1 => +"only"));                                      --(3)
  --Foo((String_Array'First => +"only"));                   --(4) prefix for "First" attribute must be constrained array
  --Foo((String_Array'Range => +"only"));                   --(5) prefix for "Range" attribute must be constrained array
  --Foo((String_Array'Range'First => +"only"));             --(6) range attribute cannot be used in expression
  --Foo((String_Array'Range'Type_Class'First => +"only"));  --(7) range attribute cannot be used in expression
end Main;
```

Comment: It's pretty idomatic in Ada to use `Positive` for the index subtype of an array used as a sequence (when you don't care what the indices are), so I would not have an issue with using `1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want (2) is indeed impossible as it could be mistaken for a parenthesized expression (see http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12aarm/html/AA-4-3-3.html note 10).

If you really want to avoid expression (3) for the reasons you stated, as workaround, you could define a function to handle the one-element array case:

```
function Singleton_String_Array (S: String) return String_Array is ((1 => + S));
-- one element call
Foo(Singleton_String_Array ("only"));
```

It reuse your expression (3) but the first index hardcoding is no longer done on call site.

You can also overload your foo function to handle the special one-element case:

```
   procedure Process_String (input : in Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String) is
   begin
      null;
   end Process_String;

   procedure Foo(input : in String_Array) is
   begin
      for string of input loop
         Process_String (string);
      end loop;
   end Foo;

   procedure Foo(input : in Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String) is
   begin
      Process_String (input);
   end Foo;
   -- One element call
   Foo(+"only");
```

Comment: ^ This. The creators of the language did not want any ambiguity in the syntax

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that all array objects must be constrained, which means callers usually have to decide on the array bounds.

However, you know the index type, and could do

```
Foo((Positive'First => +"only"));
```

which doesn't really answer your question, since someone may still fiddle with the array range, and there's not really any guard against that.

Adding a new subtype as the range may be a viable solution, though:

```
subtype String_Array_Range is Positive;
type String_Array is array (String_Array_Range range <>) of Unbounded_String;
...
Foo((String_Array_Range'First => +"only"));
```

Any fiddling can now be done on the String_Array_Range subtype without affecting any callers. But there's still no guarantee against evil programmers changing the index type of the array itself...

Answer (score 0):

```ada
type String_Array is array (Positive range <>) of Unbounded_String;
```

Declares a type of array but doesn't provide the size.
Remember that an array has a static size.

So *String_Array'First* and *String_Array'Range* don't match to anything.
If you declared

```ada
type my_String_Array is String_Array(1 .. 35);
my_arr : my_String_Array
```

Then *my_arr'First* denotes 1 and *my_arr'Range* denotes 1..35.

As long as you don't put a contraint on the type, you won't have access to these attributes.